# What is the difference between query with direct with inner join and include another select query with inner join?

Tags: sql-server

I am newly in sql, and I am confusing with these two query in sql server with inner join or another cartesian products.

Query 1:

```
SELECT TOP 3
    A.STUDENT_ID,
    A.STUDENT_NAME,
    DOB,
    CGPA,
    B.STUDENT_ID
FROM 
    STUDENT A
INNER JOIN 
    STUDENT_INFO B ON A.STUDENT_NAME = B.STUDENT_NAME
ORDER BY 
    B.STUDENT_ID ASC
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT
    A.STUDENT_ID,
    A.STUDENT_NAME,
    DOB,
    CGPA,
    C.STUDENT_ID
FROM 
    STUDENT A
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT TOP 3 * 
     FROM STUDENT_INFO 
     ORDER BY STUDENT_ID) C ON A.STUDENT_NAME = C.STUDENT_NAME
```

Below are the outputs (notice the `student_id`):

Query 1 output:

```
STUDENT_ID  STUDENT_NAME    DOB                      CGPA   STUDENT_ID
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    4       Laura           1981-12-22 00:00:00.000   3.00    400
   10       Elis            1990-10-28 00:00:00.000   3.00    400
    9       Wise            1987-11-11 00:00:00.000   3.00    499
```

Query 2 Output

```
STUDENT_ID  STUDENT_NAME    DOB                      CGPA   STUDENT_ID
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    4       Laura           1981-12-22 00:00:00.000   3.00      400
    9       Wise            1987-11-11 00:00:00.000   3.00      499
   10       Elis            1990-10-28 00:00:00.000   3.00      400
```

My question is, both join queries are the same meaning (for my understanding), but the output is a difference (query 1 are wrong and query 2 are correct which order by student_id in ascending order), so what's the difference between query 1 and query 2? Which query should we use for more accurate output?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query orders the final result set by the STUDENT_ID, so the records are in the order you expect.

The second query orders the sub-query being joined by STUDENT_ID (effectively restricting the records being joined from that table to the first 3 records, as ordered by ID), but that ordering has no effect on the subsequent JOIN. You haven't specified any ordering on the final result set, so the DB will just give you the records in whatever order it fetched them.

Comment: Hi @Peter Barton, such a great explanation! Now I get my clear information, if added ORDER BY outside the sub query, it will come out with my expected result as same output as query 1. May I ask for another question? I saw some sql that like to use subquery and not direct inner join like this, its thr any difference between use sub query or direct query? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Sql Engineer, Using a sub-query creates a result set of 3 records only, so that is all that is joined. If you just joined the table, but selected TOP 3 in the main query (I think that's what you're asking), then the two tables are fully joined, and the final answer filtered to TOP 3. Because you're joining the table against itself here, likely the exact same result set (TOP 3 records in that table are always the same, regardless of where the filtering is). But on 2 tables with different contents, the different queries would then produce different results as well.

Comment: Noted that! Thanks for your further explain ya.

Answer (score 0):

They do not mean the same. In your query 2, the `ORDER BY STUDENT_ID` is only effective for the `TOP 3` of your subquery C. In a subquery, in general ORDER BY is not accepted to use because the optimiser will not preserve ORDER BY on later join.

This is not a silly behaviour of optimisers but they have no way to preserve the ORDER BY. Imagine if you also turn `STUDENT A` into `(select top 3 * from STUDENT order by STUDENT_ID desc) A`, then should it sort it ascending or descending for you?